# << operator is crashing program with exit code 0 at some random step of printing

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, clion

I am working with opencv 3.4 and CLion 2017.3. I have built opencv with mingw and cmake, and i can use the library in my code without problem. Howewher, when i try to run this test code in main.cpp that just prints the matrix, I get a crash at some step of execution of `<<` operator:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat img(7,6, CV_8UC3, Scalar(126,0,255));
cout << img << endl << endl << endl;
cout << "end!";
```

If i run the code more than once i get these results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If i add dimentions up to some big number, the code crashes on some ~30 line or earlier

EDIT: Apparently, the problem is not related to opencv, i get this output when printing numbers from 1 to 1000 in a loop:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling anything console-related about CLion i found other corrupted console output problems. 
The proposed solution to them was to tweak the `run.processes.with.pty` setting in the `idea.properties` file. see [this YouTrack answer for details](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000117110-How-to-permanently-disable-run-processes-with-pty-in-registry-).
That solved my issue, too.